# Measuring only AC Magnetic fields (40Hz - 130 Hz range) with an arduino and a Hall effect sensor

Tags: arduino, measurement, electromagnetism

How do I measure AC electromagnetic fields (the flux density) in microTesla (µT) whilst filtering out unwanted sources of non AC magnetic radiation such as the earth with an Arduino (any microcontroller really) ?.

Answer (score 2):

> Measuring only AC Magnetic fields (40Hz - 130 Hz range) with an
>   arduino and a US1881 Hall effect sensor

You can't because the US1881 won't work; it is a latching device with a digital on/off output and severe hysterisis. It' won't give a linear output: -

[image]

Comment: Hi again! I just grabbed a Hall effect sensor off the web in the spur of the moment. Can you recommend a suiting Hall effect sensor?

Comment: @Jonathan just to remind you - I'm the guy who proposed the 50 turn coil on ferrite in your previous question and I've never used a hall sensor before - others will likely make good recommendations and I'll be keenly watching!! Did someone recommend the US1881 dude?

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm the guy who suggested to use Hall sensor, it seems that it is my responsibility to assist you in finding one :)

This answer is purely theoretical too though.

You can find a very good overview of Hall effect sensing theory and applications [here](http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=47847). While the document is very long and comprehensive, all the information directly related to your task is contained in the first four chapters. Worth reading, really.

If you read the above reference you'll understand why US1881 is not the device you are looking for (in the paper they call devices like US1881 "digital"; I don't think the name is good, because there are linear Hall sensors having digital outputs which can fit you). What you do need is a **linear** Hall effect sensor.

Let's see how many of those are out there. Go to the website of your favorite supplier and find Hall sensors category (I'm using [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/magnetic-sensors-hall-effect-digital-switch-linear-compass-ics/1967232?k=hall)). Filter the results by "type = linear". Wow, thousands of results. Too much to start checking.

How do you find a suitable one? Well, depends on your application. "Linear field sensors" sounds like the most promising direction. Filtering by this criteria reduces the list to just 12 ICs.

Out of the above 12, the A1301 seems the most simple solution, having a sensitivity of \$\sim 3 \frac{mV}{G} = 30 \frac {\mu V}{\mu T}\$ (at 6V supply voltage). It means that in order to measure the magnetic field with accuracy of 1 \$\mu T\$, the post sensor circuitry will need to resolve the voltages down to 30 \$ \mu V\$.

NOTE: since the desired accuracy is way below the ambient magnetic fields (Earth's  magnetic field is tens of uT), you'll have to make sure the sensor is very static during measurement and the post sensor circuitry will need to take care of constant offsets (calibration).